# Algorithim of how Conv2d is implemented in PyTorch

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am working on an inference model of a pytorch onnx model which is why this question is being asked.

Assume, I have a image with dimensions `32 x 32 x 3` (CIFAR-10 dataset). I pass it through a Conv2d with dimensions : `3 x 192 x 5 x 5`. The command I used is: `Conv2d(3, 192, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=2)`

Using the formula (stated here for reference pg12 https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.07285.pdf) I should be getting an output image with dimensions `28 x 28 x 192` (`input - kernel + 1 = 32 - 5 + 1`).

Question is how has PyTorch implemented this 4d tensor `3 x 192 x 5 x 5` to get me an output of `28 x 28 x 192` ? The layer is a 4d tensor and the input image is a 2d one.

How is the kernel (`5x5`) spread in the image matrix `32 x 32 x 3` ? What does the kernel convolve with first -> `3 x 192`  or `32 x 32`?

**Note** : I have understood the 2d aspects of things. I am asking the above questions in 3 or more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input to [Conv2d](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Conv2d) is a tensor of shape `(N, C_in, H_in, W_in)` and the output is of shape `(N, C_out, H_out, W_out)`, where `N` is the batch size (number of images), `C` is the number of channels, `H` is the height and `W` is the width. The output height and width `H_out`, `W_out` are computed as follows (ignoring the dilation):

```
H_out = (H_in + 2*padding[0] - kernel_size[0]) / stride[0] + 1
W_out = (W_in + 2*padding[1] - kernel_size[1]) / stride[1] + 1
```

See [cs231n](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/) for an explanation of how this formulas were obtained.

In your example `N=1, H_in = 32, W_in = 32, C_in = 3, kernel_size = (5, 5), strides = (1, 1), padding = (0, 0)`, giving `H_out = 28, W_out = 28`.

The `C_out=192` means that there are 192 different filters, each of shape `(C_in, kernel_size[0], kernel_size[1]) = (3, 5, 5)`. Each filter independently performs convolution with the input image resulting in a 2D tensor of shape `(H_out, W_out) = (28, 28)`, and since there are `C_out = 192` filters and `N = 1` images, the final output is of shape `(N, C_out, H_out, W_out) = (1, 192, 28, 28)`.

To understand how exactly the convolution is performed see the [convolution demo](https://cs231n.github.io/assets/conv-demo/index.html).

[image]

Comment: Last paragraph was the answer I was looking for. Thanks a million!